# create a dictionary of list<string> from an array of pocos?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Want to create a `dictionary<string, list<string>>`

from a result set that has a list of:

```
class catalog{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
public  bool CategoryDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

I want the key to be the CategoryName and the value to be a List of Names.

Each Categories can have the same Name associated with it. One categoryname to many reportnames and it looks like this.

```
{Name = "rp1", CategoryName=cat1, CategoryDeleted = 0 }
{Name = "rp2", CategoryName=cat1, CategoryDeleted = 0 }
{Name = "rp3", CategoryName=cat1, CategoryDeleted = 0 }
{Name = "rp1", CategoryName=cat2, CategoryDeleted = 0 }
{Name = "rp2", CategoryName=cat2, CategoryDeleted = 0 }
```

I'd like a clean linq query that does this concisely.

what I have so far:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
catalog.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
     dic.Add(x, catalog.Where(t => t.CategoryName == x).Select(t => t.ReportName).ToList());
});
```

I want to know if I can improve my query to not have to reference the catalog list twice. once to iterate and select my keys, then another to initialize the value when I make a dictionary add.

thanks!

Comment: I want to know if I can imporve my query to not have to reference the catalog list twice. once to iterate and select my keys, then another to initialize the value when I make a dictionary add.

Comment: Also note you're not iterating it twice, you're iterating it once plus once more *for each category*.

Comment: right. added now.

Comment: Use [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2) followed by [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Don't you rather need a lookup? `items.ToLookup(c => c.CategoryName, c => c.Name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one more compact solution.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = catalogs
            .GroupBy(catalog => catalog.CategoryName, catalog => catalog.Name)
            .ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key, grouping => grouping.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use grouping:

```
var dict = items.GroupBy(c => c.CategoryName).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(c => c.Name));
```